# И сразу: панибратство. Этимология

Tags: этимология

Пока писала предыдущий вопрос, задумалась над словом "панибратство". "Братство" — понятно, а "пани-"? От слова "пан"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сколько ни пытался польские переводчики заставить перевести bracie как "приятель" (или наоборот) -  безуспешно. Bracie - это брат. А вся конструкция "za panie bracie" в несколько вольном переводе означает "держать за брата". Т.е. от брата никак не уйдешь.

> а есть panie - ударение на i - более бытовое,

Откуда оно там? 
Это звательный падеж, читается как "п**а**не" с мягким н. Точно так же bracie - "бр**а**це" вокатив от brat. Ударение в польском всегда на предпоследнем слоге (ну кроме односложных слов).

//-----

При всей кажущейся очевидности польской версии, не могу не отметить странное сочетание "пани + брат". Первое - обращение к женщине, второе - от брат.

"Пани" хорошо бы объясняло греческое "pan" - всё, всёобщий.
Сравните "паникадило" - главный светильник в храме. 
Но "брат" тогда плохо объясним.

Comment: Согласна, с i- "поспешишь - людей насмешишь". Вспомнилось, что ударение у поляков всегда на предпоследнем слоге, а прочитать не удосужилась вслух - iперед е ведь не читается, указывает на мягкость. Конечно пане.Пан -более официальное обращение, пане - нейтральное, бытовое, как у нас разговорное.

Comment: Людмила, я не собираюсь ловить Вас на неточностях, просто ни о каких официальных или нейтральных обращениях речь не идет. 
Pan - именительный падеж, panie - звательный. Со всеми вытекающими. В именительном обращение невозможно. Вы, возможно, приняли за официальную форму вежливое обращение, для которой у поляков часто (может и всегда, не уверен), используется форма третьего лица, примерно так: "А не будет ли ясновельможный пан любезен...". У нас это обычно переводят как "А не угодно ли ясновельможному пану..."

Comment: – Ale koń, **panie namiestniku**, będzie nasz? – wtrącił tonem pytania wachmistrz.
– A ty, psiakrwio, chciałbyś chrześcijanowi konia w stepie odjąć?
– Bo zdobyczny...
Dalszą rozmowę przerwało silniejsze chrapanie zduszonego męża.
– Wlać mu gorzałki w gębę – rzekł **pan namiestnik** – pas odpiąć.

Henryk Sienkiewicz, "Ogniem i Mieczem"

Comment: – Уж конь то, конечно, наш будет? – поспешил спросить вахмистр.  
– А ты, подлая душа, христианина в степи без коня оставить хочешь?  
– Так ведь в бою взятый…  
Дальнейший разговор был прерван вовсе уж громким хрипением удавленного.
– Влить человеку горелки в глотку! – сказал наместник. – Да пояс на нем распустить

Answer (score 1):

http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=14.3

Есть ещё "запанибрата" - "запросто, по-товарищески, как с равным себе", может быть, "слишком бесцеремонно".
  В польском тоже есть выражение za pan brat - запанибрата.  В русском было устаревшее теперь слово панибрат, т. е. "короткий знакомый, задушевный приятель; ровня". Оно-то и произошло непосредственно из польского - из обращения pаniе bracie!, что значит: "дружище! приятель!". "Краевский сделал мне предложение, чтобы в журнале быть вроде панибрата". А. В. Кольцов. Запанибрата =  за + панибрата .

Так что "пани" в "панибрате" действительно от "пан"- вежливой формы обращения.В польском есть обращение ПАН (господин), есть ПАНИ (госпожа), а есть panie - ударение на i - более  бытовое,  чаще употребляется в идиомах, но корень этот же. Да и bracie восходит к праслав. *bratrъ, знач. кот. было более широким- "сородич, член объединения."

Comment: Но брата-то в этимологии никто не отменял? Так почему возведение к братству не проходит?

Answer (score 0):

Братство - тоже "не то". Полонизм в чистом виде:

Pаniе bracie - "приятель, короткий знакомый"

Answer (score -1):

Что такое панибратство больше могут понять на Украине или Польше, в России такой термин понятен больше на юге(Кубанцам и Донцам), панибратство в исходнике это термин характеризующий вольность общения в закрытой военной касте, где все имеют равные права кроме тех кто выбран на кругу и при исполнении (кому делегированы полномочия гетмана\атамана\сотника и т.д.), для того что полностью понять термин - надо понимать что такое боевое братство , и много других терминов ... таких к примеру что в панибратском кругу нельзя опростоволосится... , для понимания надо это рассматривать в семантике казаков \ вольных людей \ закрытого рыцарского клуба \шляхты, тогда возможно понимание сути. Панибратсво в чистом виде и казацкой семантике имеет положительный смысл.

Дословно: Паны-Браты = члены боевого братства (которые равны в правах, проверенные в боях, могут положится друг на друга, ведут общение\дискуссии\обсуждения на равных без помпезности и произношения титулов, статус их и так понятен друг другу, на кругу шапки снимают и по хохлу\чуприне\джуре\соколу и так видно кто есть кто.